# Proving that if $tX_1 + sX_2 \stackrel{D}{=} \sqrt{t^2 + s^2}X$ then $X \stackrel{D}{=} N(0, \delta^2)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, characteristic-functions

Assume that for all $s, t \in \mathbb{R}$ the following property
$$tX_1 + sX_2 \stackrel{D}{=} \sqrt{t^2 + s^2}X \tag{1}$$
is true.

Moreover $X_1, X_2, X$ are i. i. d.

My task is to prove that if $(1)$ stands then $X \stackrel{D}{=}N(0, \sigma^2)$. So $X$ is symmetrically normally distributed.

How can it be proved? I suppose that characteristic functions should be used but I have no idea how. I will appreciate any hints or tips.

Comment: Are you assuming something like $X_1$ and $X_2$ are iid, and have the same distribution as $X$?

Comment: @kimchilover Yes. I will edit my post. Thanks!

Comment: Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_theorem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 ingredients.  As you guessed, characteristic functions are involved.  Here is a hint outline.

Step 1: derive the identity $\phi(s)\phi(t)=\phi(\sqrt{s^2+t^2})$ obeyed by the characteristic function $\phi$. Then, somehow manipulate that to obtain a condition like $f(s)f(t)=f(s+t)$ or $g(s)+g(t)=g(s+t)$, valid for all real $s,t$.

Step 2: realize that this puts a severe limitation of what $f$ or $g$ (and ultimately $\phi$) can be.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can $\phi(s)\phi(t)=\phi(\sqrt{s^2+t^2})$ be manipulated? It's hard to do anything with those functions.

Comment: You have $\phi(t)\phi(0)=\phi(\sqrt{t^2})$ so $\phi(t)$ depends on $t^2$ alone.  Write it as $\phi(t)=f(t^2)$.  Now $f(a+b)=f(a+b)$ for all $\ge0$ arguments.  And so on.  As spelled out in Murthy's answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Hints: Assume that $X_1$ is not $0$ with positive probability. let $\phi$ be the characteristic function of $X_1$. Then $\phi (t) \phi (s)=\phi (\sqrt {t^{2}+s^{2}})$. If $\phi (t)=0$ for some $t$ then we get $\phi (\sqrt {t^{2}+s^{2}})=0$ for all $s$ and hence $\phi (u)=0$ for all $u >|t|$. S how that this leads to a contradiction to the given property.  Otherwise, by  a well known fact there is a continuous function $\psi$ such that $e^{\psi (t)}=\phi (t)$ and $\psi (0)=0$. Let $g(t)=\psi (\sqrt t)$ for $t >0$. Show that $g(t+s)=g(t)+g(s)$. I will leave the rest of the argument to you.